# Why does "He is as rich as any in our town" mean "He is one of the richest people in our town"?

Tags: comparisons, superlative-degree

According to my textbook, the sentence

> He is as rich as any in our town.

has the same meaning as the following one:

> He is one of the richest people in our town.

Is it right? It seems that the first sentence means he has the same amount of money as any person in the town has. But it is impossible, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Textbooks are not always right, but in this case, trust your textbook. The literal sense of the first statement, about being "as rich as any", means there is no one with more money than he, and if this is the case, then the second sentence is true, too. Completeness demands that I note that both statements have a metaphorical content.

Comment: Does your final sentence mean that neither statement is usually taken absolutely literally. If so I agree with you.

Comment: Generally, yes.

Answer (score 4):

At first glance it might seem that this sentence suggests he is as rich as people *generally* are in this town. In other words he is at the normal level of richness for people in this town.  That could be wealthy, or poor, depending on the town.

But if you examine the statement in a logical or mathematical sense, it is really saying:

> "Pick anyone randomly from this town.  He is guaranteed to be as rich as that person."

For that to be true, he must be one of the richest people in town, if not *the* richest.  That would match the textbook definition.

I don't actually agree with the textbook.  I believe the sentence could be used in either context.

I could imagine someone saying it offhand and dejectedly to mean "No, he is as poor as we all are here."

I could also imagine someone saying it proudly, with emphasis on the *any*, to mean he is the richest man in town.

So whilst logically I agree with the textbook, I am not convinced that all users of the language would use the expression that way, therefore I do not believe that the textbook definition will always be the correct interpretation.

If you wish to be precise, use another sentence entirely.

> "He is the richest man in town."
>
> "He is as poor as the rest of us."

Comment: I thought that "A is as rich as B" means "A doesn't have more money than B has and B doesn't have more money than A has". But this is clearly wrong if two sentences in my question are equivalent. Then, does "A is as rich as B" actually mean "B doesn't have more money than A has" ?

Comment: Yes literally "A is as rich as B" means "A has the same amount of money as B". But people could also use it to mean "A has as much money as B, and then some" or "A is at least as rich as B". I am sorry to say that "as X as" is often used imprecisely, perhaps more in conversation than in textbooks. You may be able to derive the true meaning from the context, or you may be left wondering.